# Show that if a metric space is complete, separable and not countable then it has cardinal $\aleph_1$

Tags: metric-spaces, cardinals

> Show that if a metric space is complete, separable and not countable then it has cardinal $\aleph_1$

I have encountered this exercise and I don't know where to start. There is a lot of important information and I can't imagine how to use it. Any hint?

Comment: Did it say $\aleph_1$ explicitly?

Comment: $\aleph_{1} = \# (\mathbb{R})$

Comment: Is there a reason to assume the continuum hypothesis for this argument?

Comment: I wouldn't know, if it helps, this exercise is right next to one that asks you to prove that: if $X$ is a metric space and $\mathcal{D}\subset X$ is a dense subspace with the following property: Every Cauchy sequence $(x_n)\subset \mathcal{D}$ converges in $X$. Show that $X$ is complete.

Comment: If your source says that $|\Bbb R|=\aleph_1$ and does not explicitly note that this is true only assuming the continuum hypothesis, then it’s wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Although the answer @Shalop contributed with is surely correct, this course is about metric spaces, not topological spaces. And that's why when dealing with the concepts of given a topology, etc, I can't follow. However, I came up with a proof, that in a similar manner, I don't see why $X$ has to be complete.

Since $X$ is separable, it contains a countable dense subset $\mathcal{D} \subset X$. We have that $\overline{\mathcal{D}}=\mathcal{D} \cup \{\text{the set of limit points of } \mathcal{D}\}=X$. (Here $\overline{\mathcal{D}}$ stands for the closure of $\mathcal{D}$).

Now, since $\mathcal{D}$ is countable, then the "number" of sequences in $\mathcal{D}$ is $\aleph_{0}^{\aleph_{0}}=\aleph_{1}$ Therefore, $\#  \{\text{the set of limit points of } \mathcal{D}\} \leq \aleph_{1}$.

However $\#  \{\text{the set of limit points of } \mathcal{D}\} > \aleph_{0}$. Because if not $\# (\overline{\mathcal{D}})=\#(\mathcal{D} \cup \{\text{the set of limit points of } \mathcal{D}\})= \# (X) = \aleph_0$ Which contradicts the fact that $X$ is not countable.

Therefore $\# (\overline{\mathcal{D}})= \# (X) = \aleph_{1}$

Comment: Yup this works, but I think that like my argument, it assumes the continuum hypothesis. You can avoid that somehow by using completeness of $X$.

Comment: I've just seen your edit. Way out of my league. HC is definetely asumed.

Comment: Your argument actually shows that $\aleph_1\le |X|\le2^{\aleph_0}$; in fact completeness implies that $|X|=2^{\aleph_0}$. Do you know the Baire category theorem?

Comment: Yes! How does Baire implies the latter?

Answer (score 2):

We will show that the cardinality of any second-countable $T_1$ space is at most $\aleph_1$, which includes this as a special case.

Let $X$ be such a space, and let $\{U_n \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a countable basis for $X$.

Let $\tau$ denote the topology (i.e, the collection of open sets) of $X$, and define a map $f: \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}) \to \tau$ as $J \mapsto \bigcup_{k\in J} U_k$. Then $f$ is surjective since $\{U_k\}$ forms a basis for $\tau$. Therefore $|\tau| \leq |\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})| = \aleph_1$.

Next, define a map $g: X \to \tau$ by $x \mapsto X \setminus \{x\}$. Then $g$ is injective, and thus $|X| \leq |\tau| \leq \aleph_1$.

**Edit:** It has been pointed out to me that the above argument only shows that $|X| \leq \aleph_1$, not that $|X| = \aleph_1$. Assuming the continuum hypothesis, this would automatically hold (given that $|X|> \aleph_0$), and we would be done.

If we don't assume CH, we can still obtain the result that $|X| \geq \aleph_1$ using complete metrizability of $X$. I don't see a truly elementary argument for this, but see theorem A.4 in the following set of notes for a terse little proof: http://www.math.tamu.edu/~kerr/book/appendixA.pdf

Comment: I think your result as it stands implies the OP's only if CH is assumed.

Comment: @triple_sec: Where exactly is CH used?

Comment: True.  We are assuming there is no set $X$ with cardinality $|\mathbb{N}| < |X| < \mathbb{R}.$   There could be a set $X$ with countable dense with this property.

Comment: The premise in the OP's question states that $\#X>\#\mathbb N$, since $X$ is uncountable. Your result implies that $\#X\leq\#\mathbb R$. To get $\#X=\#\mathbb R$, we do need the continuum hypothesis.

Comment: BTW, your answer is very neat. +1

Comment: Completeness is necessary to get $|X|=|\mathbb{R}|.$

Comment: @mattbiesecker How does completeness ensure that conclusion?

Comment: CH is assumed in the course.

Comment: @mattbiesecker I fail to see how that shows that $\#X\geq\#\mathbb R$.

Comment: You can weaken T$_1$ to T$_0$: if $X$ is a second countable T$_0$ space, then $|X|\le2^{\aleph_0}.$ Namely, let $\mathcal B$ be a countable base for the topology, then $x\mapsto\{B\in\mathcal B:x\in B\}$ is an injection from $X$ to $\mathcal P(\mathcal B).$

Comment: You seem to be assuming that the cardinality of the continuum is $\aleph_1.$ If the axiom of choice holds, then that is precisely the continuum hypothesis. Without the axiom of choice, that is stronger than the continuum hypothesis. Can't you do this without those strong assumptions, e.g. by referring just to $2^{\aleph_0}$ rather than to $\aleph_1$? $\qquad$

Comment: I rarely downvote anything, but I've downvoted this. It seems to assume $\aleph_1$ is defined as $2^{\aleph_0}.$ But ever since Cantor introduced this notation in the 19th century, $\aleph_1$ has been defined as the cardinality of the set of all countable ordinals. Cantor tried, and failed, to prove that $\aleph_1=2^{\aleph_0}.$ That proposition was later shown to be independent of the usual axioms of set theory. One shouldn't be using $\aleph_1$ as a synonym of $2^{\aleph_0}. \qquad$

Answer (score 1):

Joaquin's and Shalop's answers prove the desired result without assuming completeness but using the continuum hypothesis (CH). In fact, they show that $\#X\leq\#\mathbb R$, and for this particular result there is no reliance on the CH.

[Here](https://chiasme.wordpress.com/2013/08/05/the-continuum-hypothesis-for-borelian-sets/) is a somewhat involved proof (Lemma 2) that every uncountable Polish space (that is, separable and complete metric space) has cardinality of at least that of $\#\mathbb R$; this proof does exploit completeness. Hence, it is possible to give a complete solution to Joaquin's question without relying on the CH.